# How to change views on pressing a button in react-native (ios) without navigating to a new screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have four buttons and each button displays different information such as text, photos, map etc. I want to press a button and display information below it without navigating to a new screen.

Answer (score 0):

Make each button set the component state, and have your render method query that state. Based on what the state is, you render method can display different components.